# series of a function with comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$
a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{\log k}{k}\right)^2 
$$
is a convergent series or a divergent series. Wolfram Alpha says that by comparison test it is covergent. But I want to to know how?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily show that, for big enough $k$:

$$\frac{\log^2k}{k^2}\lt\frac{1}{k^\frac{3}{2}}\iff$$

$$\log^2k<\sqrt k\iff$$

$$\log k<\sqrt[4] k\iff$$

$$\log m^4<m\iff$$

$$\log m<\frac m4$$

...which is obviously true for big enough $m$, i.e. $k$. On the other side series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^{3/2}}$ converges so your series converges too.

Comment: Incredibly, $k$ has to be at least $5504$ for this to work! Nice job!